# How to I get this iridescent duo tone effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, duotone

[image]How to I get this iridescent duo tone effect?

I know it's probably quite simple but I have tried many different ideas and can't get it looking like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE. I have some ideas, but it's not unimportant *which* photo you want to apply the effect to. To give an answer I would first have to spend some time trying to find a free photo which would be fitting to use. Are you looking for creating a "true" duotone image which would be separated into two spot colors or do you just want it as an effect in an RGB image?

Comment: [This question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/131715/84899) is somewhat similar. Maybe you can find inspiration in my answer.

Comment: it just looks like image noise, but what have you tried? Maybe [edit] the question to add these details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airbrush Illustrator Effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131715/airbrush-illustrator-effect)